# Error With HttpContext. File Path to txt file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, filepath

I have a .txt file with a list of products. I need to add a project and use it but my file path doesn't work.
I've tried to add HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ProductList.txt");

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace AmazHumanLibrary
{
    public class ProductRepository
    {
        
         string FilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ProductList.txt");
        

        public List<Product> GetAll()
        {
            List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

            if (!File.Exists(FilePath))
            {
                var stream = File.Create(FilePath);
                stream.Close();
                return products;

            }

            string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(FilePath);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileContent))
            {
                return products;
            }

            products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(fileContent);


            return products;
        }
```

But I get the error `" The name HttpContext does not exist in the current context"`.
Here is my project structure:
[image]

Comment: Is this code in a controller action?

Comment: @mxmissile No, in my class ProductRepository

Comment: Error message is clear : You can't acces HttpContext if you are not in a web context. Your class doesn't know what an HttpContext is, this should be done in a controller. Or, you can pass a parameter to your class (like a string).

Comment: Hi ThomasHg, can you update your answer showing *where* this code is? Context is important.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier i have edit my question and add my code

Comment: Unless the code is run from some form of post-back or web web request, you don't have a http context. And that would include ajax calls - since they don't post the page back either. However, Server.Mappath should work - just not from the "non" http context which you don't have at that point in time. So it not clear why you using current context, but I don't see the need.

Answer (score 0):

To access HttpContext outside of a Controller or Razor Page, one way is to inject `IHttpContextAccessor` into your class (Repository), something like this:

```
 public class ProductRepository
 {
    public ProductRepository(IHttpContextAccessor httpContext)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContext;
    }
    
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public List<Product> GetAll()
    {
        string filePath = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/ProductList.txt");
        ...
```

Official docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-5.0).